# Finding expected indegree of a node and expected number of nodes with indegree=0

Tags: graph-theory, balls-in-bins

With a single node $v_1$, at every step $t$ with $1 < t ≤ n$, a single node $v_t$
is
added to the graph, together with a single outgoing edge; the destination of the edge is a
node chosen uniformly at random among the existing nodes in the graph.

Let $G$ be the graph at the end of time step $n$.

1. What is the expected number of edges entering node $v_j$ in $G$? Give an exact expression
   in terms of $n$ and $j$, as well as an asymptotic expression using $Θ$ notation.
2. What is the expected number of nodes with no incoming edges in $G$?

All I know so far is that $G$ cannot have self-loops nor multi-edges.

Comment: Which nodes can have an edge to $v_j$? For each of them, what is the probability of having an edge to $v_j$? This should give you the expected value. What is the probability that none of them have an edge to $v_j$?

Comment: $n*P($node entering $v_j)$. As for 2, probably $1-P($the complement of the probability of a node entering $v_j*n$? Calculating the probability left me dazed, to say the least.

Comment: There's no notion of "node entering $v_j$", is there? At least, you haven't mentioned any such thing in the question.

Comment: Edit: an edge entering $v_j$

Comment: Then the probability of a node having an edge to $v_j$ shouldn't be $n$ times that probability, that's circular. Anyway, you should be able to say what the probability of a node $v_k$ having an edge to $v_j$ is, explicitly.

Comment: Naively, 1/n. But how do I factor in nodes that already has edges pointed to them?

Comment: That shouldn't matter; when you decide where $v_k$'s edge points to, you don't check whether the destination already has edges pointing to it. But also, the probability is not $\frac1n$, because when you add $v_k$, not all the possible nodes exist yet!